# Making colorbox left align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

I am using same template for resume as was written about here, [Latex - width of the colorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125202/latex-width-of-the-colorbox).   I am trying to align the words in the black boxes to the left.   They seem to be aligned to right as default.   How can I accomplish this?

```
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}                % KOMA-article class
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}                    % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                               % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}                           % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
\textheight=700px                                   % Saving trees ;-) 
\usepackage{url}                                        % Clickable URL's
\usepackage{wrapfig}                                    % Wrap text along figures

\frenchspacing                                  % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}                               % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
\usepackage{sectsty}                            % Custom sectioning (see below)

\sectionfont{%                                  % Change font of \section command
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%                   % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}
}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}              % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}           % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{
\Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1        % Name
\par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{
\large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1} % Slogan (optional)
\par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}

\newcommand{\PersonalEntry}[2]{
\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0        % Indentation
\parbox{\spacebox}{                     % Box to align text
\textit{#1}}                                % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
\hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}                 % Entry value

\newcommand{\SkillsEntry}[2]{                       % Same as \PersonalEntry
\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0        % Indentation
\parbox{\spacebox}{                     % Box to align text
\textit{#1}}                                % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
\hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}                 % Entry value   

\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
\noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill                    % Study
\colorbox{Black}{%
\parbox{6em}{%
\hfill\color{White}#2}} \par                % Duration
\noindent \textit{#3} \par                  % School
\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4  % Description
\normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\WorkEntry}[4]{                     % Same as \EducationEntry
\noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill                    % Jobname
\colorbox{Black}{\color{White}#2} \par      % Duration
\noindent \textit{#3} \par                  % Company
\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4  % Description
\normalsize \par}



%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{-2em}
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{photo}
\end{wrapfigure}

\MyName{Your Name}
\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae}

\sepspace

%%% Personal details
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Personal details}{}

\PersonalEntry{Birth}{January 1, 1980} 
\PersonalEntry{Address}{111 First St, New York}
\PersonalEntry{Phone}{(123) 000-0000}
\PersonalEntry{Mail}{\url{me@home.com}}

%%% Education
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Education}{} 

\EducationEntry{MSc. Name of Education}{2010-2012}{Name of
University}{Descriptive text goes here. In order to maintain a stylish look, try to fill this description with a few lines of text. Do the same for the other entries in the education section.}
\sepspace

\EducationEntry{BSc. Name of Education}{2007-2010}{Name of University}{Descriptive text goes here. In order to maintain a stylish look, try to fill this description with a few lines of text. Do the same for the other entries in the education section.}

%%% Work experience
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Work experience}{}

\EducationEntry{Job name}{2011-present}{Company Name inc., Full-time}{Job description goes here. To maintain a stylish look, try to fill this description with a few lines of text. Do the same for the other entries in this section.}
\sepspace

\EducationEntry{Job name}{2010-2011}{Company Name inc., Part-time}{Job description goes here. To maintain a stylish look, try to fill this description with a few lines of text. Do the same for the other entries in this section.}

%%% Skills
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Skills}{}

\SkillsEntry{Languages}{Dutch (mother tongue)}
\SkillsEntry{}{English (fluent)}
\SkillsEntry{}{German (fluent)} 

\SkillsEntry{Software}{\textsc{Matlab}, \LaTeX, \textsc{Ansys}, \textsc{Comsol}}


%%% References
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{References}{}
Available upon request
\end{document}
```

I believe the crux of it is in the \colorbox, but I tried adding \left, but it does not work. I am not seeing any examples of changing alignment either. I look forward to any help!

```
\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
    \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill                    % Study
    \colorbox{Black}{%
    \parbox{6em}{%
    \hfill\color{White}#2}} \par                % Duration
    \noindent \textit{#3} \par                  % School
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4  % Description
    \normalsize \par}
```

EDIT: Below is a MWE incorporating the suggestion by David Carlisle. I am trying to left-align the white text in the black box. Whether I use \raggedleft or \raggedright, when I compile, the word Software appears on the right-aligned side of the box:

```
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}                % KOMA-article class
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}                    % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                               % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}                           % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
\textheight=700px                                   % Saving trees ;-) 
\usepackage{url}                                        % Clickable URL's
\usepackage{wrapfig}                                    % Wrap text along figures

\frenchspacing                                  % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}                               % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
\usepackage{sectsty}                            % Custom sectioning (see below)

\begin{document}

PUBLICATIONS

\noindent \colorbox{Black}{%
            \parbox{6em}{\raggedleft
            \hfill\color{White} Software}} 

\end{document}
```

EDIT 2:

I am noticing that this convenient line does align the text in the direction as indicated! However, for some reason, the width of the text box does not seem consistent. Below is a MWE showing this:

```
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}                % KOMA-article class
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}                    % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                               % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}                           % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
\textheight=700px                                   % Saving trees ;-) 
\usepackage{url}                                        % Clickable URL's
\usepackage{wrapfig}                                    % Wrap text along figures

\frenchspacing                                  % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}                               % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
\usepackage{sectsty}                            % Custom sectioning (see below)

\begin{document}

PUBLICATIONS

\noindent \colorbox{black}{\makebox[10em][l]{\textcolor{white}{\normalsize Software}}}
\vspace{1mm}

\noindent \small{\textbf{First software here}

\noindent \colorbox{black}{\makebox[10em][l]{\textcolor{white}{\normalsize Articles}}}
\vspace{1mm}

\noindent \small{\textbf{First article here}

\noindent \small{\textbf{Second article here}

\noindent \small{Third article here}

\noindent \colorbox{black}{\makebox[10em][l]{\textcolor{white}{\normalsize Book chapters}}}
\vspace{1mm}

\noindent \small{First book chapter here}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @you should remove the `\hfill` and then `\raggedleft` makes everything flush to the right margin of the box or `\raggedright` makes everything flush to the left edge. or if it is just a single line you don't need a `\parbox` at all (which is for paragraphs) \colorbox{black}{\makebox[6em][l]{\textcolor{white}{Software}}}`  and then use `[l]`, `[c]` or `[r]` depending what alignment you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! That does seem to work! But I do find it strange that the width of the box can change when I use the same [6em]. I am sorry to ask another question: I added a second Edit with a MWE where I am using your line mentioned above (Which is very convenient) three times, but the output gives three boxes of different widths. By the way, I can reopen in another thread, if that is recommended.

Comment: please do not keep editing the question with partial solutions, it makes the existing answers not understandable.  Your use of `\small` is wrong, it does not take an argument so as used above the first `\small` makes the entire document small and changes the size of 1em for the rest of the document.

Comment: Ideally in a document you should have no space/indentation controls, no font changes and no font size changes and in one small space you have all three: `\noindent \small{\textbf{`   even if you fixed that to `\noindent {\small\textbf{` it would be really horrible markup. The idea of latex is you use something like \section{Software}\begin{description}\item....` and all the fonts and spacing and colour are specified elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

to right align text in a `\parbox` use

```
  \parbox{6em}{\raggedleft
```

(The colorbox is not really involved at all)

Comment: Thank you for your support!  I may be misinterpreting your advice, but I still seem to have the same issue. I am trying to left-align the text in the box, but whether I use \raggedleft or \raggedright, the text appears right-aligned. I added an Edit with a MWE to illustrate my issue. Thanks again.