# How can I adjust the starting position of the next line?

Tags: fonts

I used the code as below to create the duration of my working experience. Because of space, the output would be like the attached screenshot. 
I tried to make align to the right by "flushright" but failed.
Any ideas would be highly appreciated :)

[image]

```
\EducationEntry{Revenue Officer}
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{July 2014-July 2017}
\end{flushright}

{Taxation Bureau of Taipei, Ministry of Finance, Full-time}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item drafted taxation auditing reports
\item managed public relation and media liaison affairs with mass media
\item served as the initial contact of foreign guests' and school visits
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Could you please attach a chunk of code that compiles, a proper minimum working example.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `\EducationEntry` accepts four possible arguments; `{Job name}{Duration}{Company Name, Part/Full-time}{Job description}`, so, instead of formatting your own dates, just add the dates in the second pair of parentheses like this:

```
\EducationEntry{Revenue Officer}{July 2014-July 2017}
{Taxation Bureau of Taipei, Ministry of Finance, Full-time}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item drafted taxation auditing reports
\item managed public relation and media liaison affairs with mass media
\item served as the initial contact of foreign guests' and school visits
\end{itemize}
}
\sepspace
```

[image]

The full code for the CV is available in an answer to a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125203/59109).